# Having a little trouble overriding React-Bootstrap css using Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass, next.js, react-bootstrap

Here's the situation. I'm trying to override default bootstrap styling for the NavBar component in react-bootstrap. I am trying to just change the background color and text color.

Currently, the background color is correctly changing to black, however, the foreground text color, is not changing to white, as in specifying in the scss file.

Here is my navigation component file (that contains the bootstrap navbar) that im returning to the layout component

```
import {NavDropdown, Navbar, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap' 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import styles from '../styles/Navigation.module.scss'


    const Navigation = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar className={styles.navbar}>
                    <Nav className={styles.nav}>
                        <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/instructions">How to Use</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/donate">Donate</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/changelog">Changelog</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/feedback">Feedback</Nav.Link>
                        <NavDropdown title="Compositional Toolkit">
                            <Nav.Item>More Tools Coming Soon!<br/>Click here to be emailed notifications!</Nav.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
    
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Navigation
```

And here is the Navigation.module.sass file

```
.navbar {
    background: #000;
    .nav {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Probably just something stupid that i'm missing, but if i'm going about this all wrong, please let me know if there is a better method for doing this, i'm still pretty new to using all these frameworks and stuff all together, so i apologize if this is kind of a simple, amateurish question.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from setting the color on `Nav.Link` (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68478864/11613622)), it appears to be an issue of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/specificity). You can try doing:

```css
color: #fff !important;
```

Also, you can try using `<Navbar bg="dark">`. And if you don't like the default grey color, then you can easily override them as you are already using SCSS in your project. Refer: [Theming Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)

Another thing that I would like to highlight, import Bootstrap styles in [`_app.jsx`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet) if you are using it in your whole website. And, wrap your `Nav.Link`s in [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) like this:

```js
<Link href="/" passHref>
    <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
</Link>
```

Comment: Could not have asked for a better answer. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

You defined the color of the Nav component. Setting the color of the Nav.Link as white will solve the problem.

Comment: So, i moved the className={styles.nav} to the Nav.Link element instead, and it unfortunately is still not showing up white